# Como parar três loopings for em C

Tags: c, inteligência-artificial

Rstou tentando implementar o algoritmo de busca ordenada de Inteligência artificial e cheguei a um ponto que preciso parar todos os loopings, caso eu tenha encontrado o NÓ procurado.

Vejam o trecho que fiz, mas não dá certo. Sei que em PHP eu poderia usar o break 3 para finalizar as três iterações, mas no C não funciona nem encontrei na internet:

```
for(int i=0;i<N;i++) {
   for(int j=0;j<N;j++){
      if(entra){
         soma = 0;
         custo = 99999;
         for(int k=0;k<N;k++){
            if (abertos[k] > 0){
                //se o nó estiver em fechados, pula para próxima iteração.
                if (fechados[k]==1){
                    continue;
                }
                if(mCusto[k] < custo){
                    custo = mCusto[k];
                    posatual = k;
                }

                if (posatual+1 == dest){ //Se chegou ao destino então para o looping.
                    printf("Sucesso\n\n");
                    break;
                    break;
                    break;
                }
            }
            soma += abertos[k];
            printf("\nsoma = %d\n",soma);
            fechados[posatual] = 1; //coloca o nó escolhido em fechados.
        } //fim laço k
```

Comment: Algo me diz que alguém vai postar um quadrinho do xkcd na resposta.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A primeira resposta que veio a cabeça, tenho quase certeza que tem alguma maneira mais sofisticada de fazer isso.

```
int i, j, k;
int stop = 0;

for(i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    for(j = 0; j < 10; ++j) {
        for(k = 0; k < 10; ++k) {
            if(/* Alguma condição aleatória*/) {
                stop = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(stop) {
            break;
        }
    }
    if(stop) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Fora essa, só lembro do `goto`, porém o mesmo tem uso desencorajado em C.

Comment: Boa, vou seguir dessa maneira mesmo, obrigado.

Answer (score 7):

Achei esta solução no [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9695902/breaking-of-nested-loop) em inglês, existem outras.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < 1000; i++) {
        if(condition) {
            goto end;
    }
} 

end:
```

Comment: Nesse caso o uso do `goto` é aceitável, mas gostaria de deixar um alerta: se seu código possui [sessões críticas](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regi%C3%A3o_cr%C3%ADtica), você **nunca** deve entrar/sair delas através de um `goto`.

Comment: Hum, não sabia que podia usar GoTo em C, uso esse comando para tratar erros para uma saída em VBA.
Então eu defino o rótulo como saida no último laço e em seu conteúdo coloco break;

`for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {

    for(int j = 0; j < 1000; i++) {

        if(condition) {

            goto saida;

    }

} 


saida:

break;
`
Correto?

Comment: @Luiz a "saída" seria uma forma de sair do loop e continuar o código externo. Não possuo muitos conhecimentos em C, apenas achei esta solução. Melhor você usar a solução na qual você já escolheu.

Comment: No SO você ganha um banimento automático se incluir "C" e "Goto" na mesma página :-P (brincadeira, mas até perguntar sobre C e goto gera downvotes em massa).

Answer (score 4):

Ao ver uma função com tantos leveis de identação um dentro do outro a primeira coisa que vem em mente é: *está função está fazendo demais*.

Em um munto ideal, cada função deve ter uma funcionalidade bem especifica e isolada e se basear em outras funções mais triviais para fazer sua operação. Para casos como o seu vale a pena rever a organização do código e fazer algum *refactoring* para dividir a tarefa em mais que uma função.

---

Respondendo mais diretamente à pergunta: existe uma operação mágica capaz de quebrar quantos níveis forem necessários: `return`. Se o objetivo é procurar por algum nodo, você pode fazer assim:

```
int findNode(int a, int b, int c, int d, .../*stuff you need*/) {
    for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        for (j = 0; j < 10; ++j) {
            for (k = 0; k < 10; ++k) {
                if (/*algo*/)
                    return a+b*c-d;
            }
        }
    }
}

// Mais para frente...
int dest = findNode(34, 64, aaa, y+f);
fazerAlgoCom(dest);
```

Comment: Essa sua resposta é a melhor na minha opinião, ela só vai ser um problema em casos o código for muito complexo e for  necessário usar muitas variáveis dentro dos loops, o que pode fazer o cabeçalho da função ficar estranhamente grande ou você ter que abusar dos argumentos dinâmicos do `va_*`.

Comment: Isso tudo são casos de um código mal organizado, com funcionalidades não tão bem planejadas. Ai cabe modularizar e fazer mais uso de structs. Ter tantos argumentos assim é um sinal, não o problema em si. Tratar de sintomas não é cura.

Comment: Pensei nessa possibilidade, porém declarei a função como void.

Comment: @Cahe É para isso que servem as structs e os princípios da orientação de objetos (que sim, podem ser aplicados no C).