# Por que o break não está funcionando?

Tags: c, matriz

Enunciado:

> Leia uma matriz 5x5. Leia tambem um valor X. O programa devera fazer
>   uma busca desse valor na matriz e, ao final, escrever a localizacao
>   (linha e coluna) ou mensagem de "nao encontrado"

Código:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define TAM 5

int main(){
    int matriz[TAM][TAM], c, c2, num, p1, p2;
    bool aux;

    for (c=0; c<TAM; c++){
        for (c2=0; c2<TAM; c2++){
            scanf("%d", &matriz[c][c2]);
        }
    }

    printf("Que numero deseja encontrar? ");
    scanf("%d", &num);

    for (c=0; c<TAM; c++){
        aux = false;

        for (c2=0; c2<TAM; c2++){
            if (matriz[c][c2] == num){
                p1 = c;
                p2 = c2;
                aux = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if (aux){
        printf("[%d][%d]", p1, p2);
    } else {
        printf("Numero nao encontrado. ");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

E o problema é o seguinte, quando coloco para encontrar um valor que está no início da matriz ele não encontra, apenas do final.

Alguém pode me explicar por que acontece isso?

Comment: eu fui fazenso algus testes, e ele simplesmente nao para de testar quando entra no if. como fazer ele parar?

Comment: O `break`, no [tag:c], só é capaz de quebrar um único laço. Pelo que entendi, você quer sair de ambos os laços (tanto o mais interno quanto o mais externo), correto?

Comment: Isso mesmo! como posso fazer isso?

Comment: De modo fácil sem usar funções? Não recomendo, acho que só `goto`. A resposta para a sua pergunta você encontra aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/12346/64969 ; ou aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/97300/64969

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O `break` para sempre só o loop de dentro. Logo analisando o seu código:

```
for (c=0; c<TAM; c++){
    aux = false;

    for (c2=0; c2<TAM; c2++){ // este é o loop que para
        if (matriz[c][c2] == num){
            p1 = c;
            p2 = c2;
            aux = true;
            break; // quando este break é executado
        }
    }
}
```

Existem várias formas de resolver este problema.

### Múltiplos breaks

Uma das formas de resolver é voltar a fazer `break` no `for` que está fora se já fez `break` no `for` de dentro. Isto torna-se mais complicado ou chato consoante tem mais `fors` para quebrar.

No seu exemplo ficaria assim:

```
for (c=0; c<TAM; c++){
    aux = false;

    for (c2=0; c2<TAM; c2++){
        if (matriz[c][c2] == num){
            p1 = c;
            p2 = c2;
            aux = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (aux){ //se apanhou true e teve um break no outro for, faz break a este tambem
        break;
    }
}
```

Se tivesse mais `fors` teria que continuar a fazer mais `if` `break` até sair de todos.

### Funções

Com funções também resolve o problema, e na minha opinião é uma solução bem melhor, pois quando quer sair dos `fors` todos basta fazer um `return`. Isto só por si evita quaisquer variáveis que funcionem como *flags* que indicam se deve terminar ou não, o que simplifica o código. Para além disso acaba por abstrair uma parte da lógica que tem no seu programa para uma função à parte, simplificando consideravelmente a interpretação e leitura.

No seu exemplo tem o pormenor de obter os valores achados de volta, que também dá para fazer de várias maneiras. Irei exemplificar com uma função que devolve um booleano a indicar se achou, e atualiza dois ponteiros para os valores apropriados caso tenha encontrado:

```
bool posicao_numero(int matriz[TAM][TAM], int num, int *linha_num, int *coluna_num){
    int c, c2;
    for (c=0; c<TAM; c++){
        for (c2=0; c2<TAM; c2++){
            if (matriz[c][c2] == num){
                *linha_num = c;
                *coluna_num = c2;
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Agora no main a utilização seria:

```
if (posicao_numero(matriz, num, &p1, &p2)){
    printf("[%d][%d]", p1, p2);
} else {
    printf("Numero nao encontrado. ");
}
```

[Veja este exemplo no Ideone](https://ideone.com/ZTQjiv)

Answer (score 1):

No primeiro **for** você está definindo a variavel **aux** como false, assim quando ele acha a posição do numero na matriz no segundo **for** e coloca a varivel **aux** como true ele sai do segundo **for** e volta pro primeiro que coloca a varivel como false novamente. Tente definir a varivel **aux** como false fora do **for**, assim:

```
aux = false;
for (c=0; c<TAM; c++){
    for (c2=0; c2<TAM; c2++){
        if (matriz[c][c2] == num){
            p1 = c;
            p2 = c2;
            aux = true;
        }
    }
}

if (aux){
    printf("[%d][%d]", p1, p2);
} else {
    printf("Numero nao encontrado. ");
}
```

Comment: Continua dando a encrenca de não parar o laço.

Comment: Mas resolve o problema de não encontrar o valor no inicio da matriz, que ela menciona no final da pergunta, creio que ela nem precise do break nesse caso especifico.