# Retornando Múltiplos valores

Tags: c, matriz, lógica

O seguinte código manda colocarmos uma sequencia de números na seguinte matriz e depois atribuir um valor para X e procurar se o valor de X é igual a algum valor da matriz. Porém está me retornando como mostrando no "Output" abaixo. Como resolver??

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>


int main(){


setlocale(LC_ALL, "");




int matriz[5][5], i, j;



for(i = 1; i <= 5; i++){
    for(j = 1; j <= 5; j++){


        printf("Matriz[%d][%d]: ", i, j);
        scanf("%d", &matriz[i][j]);

    }
}



int X;
printf("\n\nAgora vamos ler um valor X: ");
scanf("%d", &X);





for(i = 1; i <= 5; i++){
    for(j = 1; j <= 5; j++){


       if(X == matriz[i][j]){

        printf("\nEstá na linha: %d coluna: %d", i, j);
        

       }else{

       printf("\nNão Encontrado!! :(");
        
       }

    }
}

return 0;
}
```

Input

```
Matriz[1][1]: 1
Matriz[1][2]: 2
Matriz[1][3]: 3
Matriz[1][4]: 4
Matriz[1][5]: 5
Matriz[2][1]: 6
Matriz[2][2]: 7
Matriz[2][3]: 8
Matriz[2][4]: 9
Matriz[2][5]: 10
Matriz[3][1]: 11
Matriz[3][2]: 12
Matriz[3][3]: 13
Matriz[3][4]: 14
Matriz[3][5]: 15
Matriz[4][1]: 16
Matriz[4][2]: 17
Matriz[4][3]: 18
Matriz[4][4]: 19
Matriz[4][5]: 20
Matriz[5][1]: 21
Matriz[5][2]: 22
Matriz[5][3]: 23
Matriz[5][4]: 24
Matriz[5][5]: 25


Agora vamos ler um valor X: 16
```

Output

```
Não Encontrado!! :(
Não Encontrado!! :(
Não Encontrado!! :(
Não Encontrado!! :(
Não Encontrado!! :(
Não Encontrado!! :(
Não Encontrado!! :(
Não Encontrado!! :(
Não Encontrado!! :(
Não Encontrado!! :(
Não Encontrado!! :(
Não Encontrado!! :(
Não Encontrado!! :(
Não Encontrado!! :(
Não Encontrado!! :(
Está na linha: 4 coluna: 1
Não Encontrado!! :(
Não Encontrado!! :(
Não Encontrado!! :(
Não Encontrado!! :(
Não Encontrado!! :(
Não Encontrado!! :(
Não Encontrado!! :(
Não Encontrado!! :(
```

Gostaria que a saída não imprimisse esses vários *"Não Encontrado!! :("*

Comment: Não entendi a pergunta. Explique como você gostaria que ficasse a saída?

Comment: @AugustoVasques Não imprimindo esses vários "Não encontrado", era pra imprimir essa frase apenas se o valor de X for diferente de algum valor na Matriz[i][j], porém não é o que está acontecendo ai

Comment: Arrays em C são indexados em zero: o primeiro elemento está no índice zero, o segundo no índice 1 e assim por diante. Então acessar `[5]` já está errado. O problema é que a linguagem não "reclama", e dependendo do compilador/ambiente pode até "funcionar", mas será por "sorte"/coincidência. Dito isso, a resposta abaixo dá uma dica de como fazer (guardar uma variável com o resultado da busca e só imprimir depois do `for` - mas com o detalhe que ela não alertou para o problema dos índices)

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Por que o break não está funcionando?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/316272/por-que-o-break-n%c3%a3o-est%c3%a1-funcionando) - apesar do título não ter nada a ver, leia as respostas que tem lá, que mostra como fazer o que vc quer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resumidamente, está imprimindo `Não Encontrado!! :(` várias vezes por quê a condição está dentro de um laço de repetição.

Antes de tudo: arrays em C começam no `zero`. O que isso quer dizer? Sua matriz tem 5 x 5 posições e você teoricamente esta usando apenas 4 x 4 delas. Você está utilizando somente os elementos que tem 1. Os que tem 0 você está desperdiçando.

```
0 0 0 0 0  
0 1 1 1 1 
0 1 1 1 1 
0 1 1 1 1 
0 1 1 1 1
```

Então declare a matriz da seguinte forma para ter 5 x 5 posições:

```
int matriz[5][5]
```

Dessa forma, você você tem 5 possibilidades de posição: `0,1,2,3,4`. A sua matriz fica assim:

```
1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1
```

Agora para o seu problema. Repare que no trecho:

```
//Você percorre CADA elemento da matriz
for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    for(j = 0; j < 5; j++){

       //Se o elemento matriz[i][j] está na matriz, então imprima sua posição
       if(X == matriz[i][j]){

        printf("\nEstá na linha: %d coluna: %d", i, j);
        
       //Se o elemento matriz[i][j] não está nessa matriz, imprima Não encontrado
       }else{

       printf("\nNão Encontrado!! :(");
        
       }

    }
}
```

Você faz a comparação para cada elemento. Logo, se o elemento `matriz[i][j]` não é igual ao valor procurado, você irá imprimir não encontrado. Como você passa elemento por elemento, a mensagem é impressa várias vezes.
Para resolver isso alguma soluções são possíveis. Uma delas é: sinalizar que o elemento foi encontrado:

```
bool stop = false;
//Percorra CADA elemento da matriz, se foi encontrado o elemento foi encontrado ou i < 5 você para.
for(i = 0; i < 5 && !stop ; i++){
    for(j = 0; j < 5 && !stop; j++){

       //Se o elemento matriz[i][j] está na matriz, então imprima sua posição e pare os laços.
       if(X == matriz[i][j]){

        printf("\nEstá na linha: %d coluna: %d", i, j);
        stop = true;
       
       }

    }
}
//Se o elemento não foi encontrado ( em nenhum momento passou para true )

if(!stop){
   printf("\nNão Encontrado!! :(");
}
```